# ExtJS: checkbox click or keyup event

Tags: javascript, extjs

Now I can handle `change` event of a `checkbox` in my `controller`. I do it like so:

```
"[itemId=TestCheckbox]": {
   change: this.updateCheckbox
}
```

What I do not like about this, is that this event fires even when the state of the checkbox is changed programmatically - when, for example, the value is bound at the first time. All this results in unnecessary server requests:

1. First request gets data from the server and binds the value to the checkbox
2. Change event is fired and another server request is done

I do not like this. I want something like keyup event, or check event, so that I could trigger server request, only when the state of the checkbox is changed by hand and not programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a `mousedown/keydown` handler to the checkbox `el`, then setting a flag there, and check for that flag in the change event handler

```
{
    xtype:     'checkboxfield',
    listeners: {
        mousedown: {
            element: 'el',
            fn:      function (e, el) {
                Ext.getCmp(e.currentTarget.id).myFlag = true
            }
        },
        change:    function (cb, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            console.log(cb, cb.myFlag)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: It's works fine for me.
I've also add event on keyboard because user can switch checkbox with space bar.

`keyup: {
 element: 'el',
 fn: 'onKeyUp'
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **setValue** to set value to combo, it fires change event .
Check [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-change)

You can use **suspendEvents** and  **resumeEvents** to avoid this.

Call **suspendEvents** before setting value and call **resumeEvents(true)** after setting value.

**suspendEvents** will bloack all events fired by **setValue** and **resumeEvents** will agaib resume firing events . Don't forget to pass true argument to resumeEvents

```
combo.suspendEvents();
combo.setValue(value);
combo.resumeEvents(true);
```

Read more about [suspendEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#method-suspendEvents) and [resumeEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#method-resumeEvents).

Comment: No, I'm not using `setValue`. As I said,I use binding.